# What's a good way to split a 'item_list' into two columns?

Tags: theming

I'm working in a custom module that will output to my custom theme in D7. This theme & module will never be used apart.

Say I have a simple list in a block (six items), I want it split into two adjacent columns of three items...

1. Can this be done only with CSS? (just curious, not a constraint)
2. What seems easier; should I render two lists & just float the second right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this just using CSS by giving the list items a width and floating left:

```
.list-class li { width: 50%; float: left; }
```

You might need to adjust the width to a static number depending on the padding you have on the `<li>`s.

Comment: Yep, the above (with a static width) worked perfect